# Signing a PDF using a X.509 SmartCard certificate with iText in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a SmartCard (governement eID) from which I can extract a signature (Non-repudiation) certificate after inserting a pin, using the SmartCard specific API and drivers, which can return a byte[] for each certificate that the card holds. After researching I've found that this is a X.509 certificate and in Java you can get an object out of it using the following code:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(certByteArray);
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
```

My questions:

- Is it possible to sign a document using a X.509 certificate? I've read and experimented a lot about this subject (I have a program that manipulates and sign's a PDF with iText, using a PKCS#12 ) but the only references I see regarding X.509 are about encryption, even in [Bruno Lowagie's white paper](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf).
- If so, how can it be done using the BouncyCastle crypto provider?

Comment: Are you wanting to just sign it or encrypt it?

Comment: *sign a document using a X.509 certificate?* - a certificate in essence is a wrapper for a public key, but to sign a document you need to apply the private key located on the smart card.

Comment: Please read http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures to find out how to sign a PDF document using a smart card. As the two comments already indicated: you don't sign a document with a public key certificate! If that were possible, you'd have a serious security problem.

Comment: @BrianC just digitally sign.

As this eID card has a government specific API and it does provide a way to get the X.509 certificates, I wanted to be sure that I wasn't missing out on something before going through other ways (as I had already glanced at the smartcard signing topics in your white paper @BrunoLowagie).

Comment: Thank you @mkl and Bruno for clearing that up !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling to authenticate / sign something using the Portuguese eID (named *Cartão Cidadão*), the provided java lib with the middleware only implements public methods to get the certificates used for verification, this puzzled me as I was expecting to have access to everything.

To solve this you can use the pteidpkcs11.dll native methods, which is installed with the middleware (System32 folder in a Windows system). I'm still trying to create a code sample which can accomplish this but here are my current leads:

- Use [pteid4j](https://github.com/andremanuelbarbosa/pteid4j) lib. Keep in mind that the iText code example regarding pdf signature is old and doesn't exist in the latest build
- Implement the code in the topic "Signing a document using PKCS#11", in [itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might struggle less on the matters of **authentication / signing** with the portuguese eID (Cartão de Cidadão) if you try a java component by the name of poreid located on [www.poreid.org](http://www.poreid.org) and available on maven central repository with the artifactid poreid

An example based on the samples provided on [itext website](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=222)

```
public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Assinado com o Cartão de Cidadão!"));
    document.close();
}

public void signPdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(POReIDConfig.POREID);
    ks.load(null);
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(POReIDConfig.AUTENTICACAO, null);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(POReIDConfig.AUTENTICACAO);

    // reader and stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');

    // appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper .getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason("qualquer motivo");
    appearance.setLocation("qualquer localização");
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72, 732, 144, 780), 1, "primeira assinatura");

    // digital signature
    ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", POReIDConfig.POREID);
    ExternalDigest digest = new ProviderDigest(null); // find provider
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Security.addProvider(new POReIDProvider());

    App exemplo = new App();
    exemplo.createPdf("/home/quim/exemplo.pdf");
    exemplo.signPdf("/home/quim/exemplo.pdf","/home/quim/exemplo.assinado.pdf");
}
```